# Disable APC Debugging?

Tags: php, apc

Is the APC Debugging mode really needed? How can I disable it?
I can't find a setting for it http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

```
Version     3.1.9
APC Debugging   Enabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask no value
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 308812 $
Build Date  Jun 18 2011 18:33:59
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it by either compiling yourself or going back to an older version. See [Bug #18890  APC debug mode is enabled by default](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18890).